# Matched leaf route at location "/cadastro" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to solve this for a few hours now, everything I do returns this same error.

Matched leaf route at location "/cadastro" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

routes.js file

```
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

import Cadastro from "./pages/cadastro";
import CadastroGuiasTuristicos from "./pages/cadastro-guia-turistico";
import DetalhesGuiasTuristicos from "./pages/detalhes-guias-turistico";
import GuiasTuristicos from "./pages/guias-turisticos";
import Home from "./pages/home";
import Login from "./pages/login";
import PlanoEstabelecimentos from "./pages/plano-de-assinatura/estabelecimentos";
import PlanoGuias from "./pages/plano-de-assinatura/guias-turisticos";

const RoutesTeste = () => {
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" component={ <Home/> }></Route>
        <Route path="/cadastro" component={ <Cadastro/> }></Route>
        <Route path="/cadastro-guia-turisticos" component={ <CadastroGuiasTuristicos/> }></Route>
        <Route path="/detalhes-guias-turisticos" component={ <DetalhesGuiasTuristicos/> }></Route>
        <Route path="/guias-turisticos" component={ <GuiasTuristicos/> }></Route>
        <Route path="/login" component={ <Login/> }></Route>
        <Route path="/estabelecimentos" component={ <PlanoEstabelecimentos/> }></Route>
        <Route path="/guias-turisticos" component={ <PlanoGuias/> }></Route>
      </Routes>  
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
export default RoutesTeste;
```

App.js

```
import RoutesTeste from './routes';

export default function App() {
 return (
     <RoutesTeste/>
 );
}
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Are you using `react-router-dom@6`? They changed `component` to `element`, see: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#configuring-routes

Comment: I made this conversion "<Route path="/cadastro" component={ <Cadastro/> }></Route>"

Comment: If you're using v6, it should be `<Route path="/cadastro" element={ <Cadastro/> } />`.

Comment: It didn't work the same

Answer (score 5):

In Route ,change **component to element**.

Instead of -
<Route path="/" component={  }>
<Route path="/cadastro" component={  }>

do this-

<Route path="/" element={  }>
<Route path="/cadastro" element={  }>

for all the Route.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the component with element as follows;

```
<Route path="/" element={ <Home/> }></Route>
```

It will work...